# How to concatenate sql table column with same (name) value in different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

Let's suppose I have this table:

```
1|A|B|10
2|A|B|20
3|B|C|20
```

How to write a query to get this value:

```
1|A|B|10,20
3|B|C|20
```

Comment: what have you tried yourself so far? what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](/q/43870/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT MIN(column_1) AS min_value
, column_2
, column_3
, STRING_AGG(column_4 ORDER BY column_4, ' ')
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_2, column_3
ORDER BY MIN(column_1);
```

Comment: Judging by the expected output in the question, the OP is probably looking for `string_agg()` rather than `array_agg()`